# Scrape data from near non structured html page to google sheet automatically

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets

Is it possible to **scrape**  a data from nonstructured html page to googlesheet automatically? meaning, the moment that html page adds a new list, it will automatically be added to google sheet, as well as the data distributed in columns as provided in the diagram.

[image: diagram to clarify]

Comment: depends........

Comment: the answer is entirely dependent on exactly the page to be scraped.  there is no "universal" way to do it.  Many webpages take steps to prevent this kind of scraping.